# Ocultar y mostrar hojas de excel desde python

Tags: python, excel

Estoy intentando `ocultar` y `mostrar` algunas `hojas` de `excel` usando `openpyxl`, pero no encuentro documentación en español sobre el particular.

Existe un método dentro de `openpyxl` que permita hacer lo anterior, o tal vez usando alguna otra `librería`.

Answer (score 0):

Sobre la `hoja` que se requiere ocultar o mostrar existe el método `".sheet_state"`, al usarlo sobre la `hoja` respectiva se tiene que asignar el valor `'hidden'` o `'visible'` para ocultar o mostrar respectivamente.

Aquí una pequeña implementación mostrando su uso

```
from openpyxl import Workbook
import openpyxl

libro = "libroOcultarHojas.xlsx"
# se crea un archivo que al final se salvará
miLibro = Workbook()

# o si ya se tiene el archivo
# indicar la ruta también
# si este script no se encuentra en
# la misma carpeta
# -----------------------------------------
# miLibro = openpyxl.load_workbook(libro)
# -----------------------------------------

print(miLibro.sheetnames)
#['Sheet'] o las hojas si el archivo ya existe

# Se renombra 'Sheet' por 'miHoja1'
miLibro.active.title = 'miHoja1'

# Se crea 3 hojas más
for i in range(2, 5):
    miLibro.create_sheet("miHoja" + str(i))

# muestra el total de hojas contenidas en el libro
print(miLibro.sheetnames)
#['miHoja1', 'miHoja2', 'miHoja3', 'miHoja4']

# se emplea el método "sheet_state"
# sobre miHoja2 de miLibro y se le dice 'hidden'
# ocultar
miLibro['miHoja2'].sheet_state = 'hidden'

# se verifica
for hoja in miLibro.sheetnames:
    print(hoja,":",miLibro[hoja].sheet_state) 
# miHoja1 : visible
# miHoja2 : hidden
# miHoja3 : visible
# miHoja4 : visible

miLibro['miHoja3'].sheet_state = 'hidden'  # ocultar
miLibro['miHoja3'].sheet_state = 'visible' # visible

# se guarda
miLibro.save(libro)
```

El resultado final:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]